# Run Spring Boot JAR with predefined profile

Tags: java, spring, jar, executable-jar

I'm trying to run my JAR file with the `java -jar sample.jar` command and I'm using `application.yml` configuration file with the following setup

```yml
spring:
  profiles:
    active:
      - dev
---
server:
  port: 8081
spring:
  profiles: dev
---
server:
  port: 8082
spring:
  profiles: test
```

But the application doesn't recognize the profile giving back the information of
`No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default` and setting up the port to default 8080

I tried things like
`java -jar sample.jar -Drun.jvmArguments=-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` or
`java -jar sample.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

In my `pom.xml` file the only change I made was adding `<packaging>jar</packaging>` property.

From what I've learned maven profiles are completely different things and shouldn't influence spring profiles.

I don't know where to look for the problem as when I start the app by *Run* button in Intellij IDEA it works perfectly and recognizes every profile set up as active.

The actual question here is **how to set up default profile to run while building an artifact** so there's no need to place extra flags in the terminal command running the jar.

I know there's a lot of questions like mine but most of their accepted answers doesn't work in my case and the rest is unanswered. If you know what might be an issue here, please let me know. Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 12):

You can activate profile through **command line** argument. In your trying, you are defining the active profile after the name of the jar. You need to provide the program argument before the name of the jar you are running.

```sh
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev  sample.jar
```

An alternative way to set the active profile is to create a `application.properties` file with the following property:

```
spring.profiles.active=prod
```

Comment: So the order here is important - `java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev  sample.jar` command managed to set the profile to the `dev` but no changes in configuration were made. While the `dev` profile is active I expect the app to run on port 8081 but still got default value of 8080. Do you know what causes this behaviour?

Comment: I just moved from `application.properties` to `application.yml` and wrote the same settings as were in application.properties.

Comment: Is your `application.yml` file located at the right place? Is Spring logging that it loaded your file at startup?

Comment: It's in the same place as the `application.properties` was. It says right after the command `20:43:46.096 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'spring.profiles.active' in PropertySource 'systemProperties' with value of type String
20:43:46.099 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Activating profiles [dev]` but still no configuration is loaded - port is set to default

Comment: Everything seems to be right. It is hard to debug this kind of erros without access to full source code to check if something is missconfigured. One more thing I would try is to open the generated jar and check if the `application.yml` is there. 
I know this is not what you are looking for, but you can also change the port through command line argument: `java -jar -Dserver.port=8081 sample.jar`

Comment: My jar is under `out/artifacts/sample_jar/sample.jar` and there's nothing else. Moreover - how do I look into jar file?

Comment: The jar is just a zip file. You can open it using any application that opens zip files.

Comment: I just copied and pasted you application.yml to a project here and it was loaded. Try to create a new project with spring initializer to perform an isolated test: https://start.spring.io/

Answer (score 2):

With Spring-Boot 3+ and JDK 21

`java -jar  .\path\to\jar\app.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev`